# Grammar stripping isPalindrome function for Haskell

Tags: haskell, palindrome, strip

Just to make sure there's no confusion.

**I am not asking how to write a regular palindrome finder.**

I know that would be a repeat question.

I know that to find a palindrome you use

```
isPalindrome :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
isPalindrome xs = xs == (reverse xs)
```

This would return true for "madamimadam".

What I can't figure out is the function that would return true for "Madam I'm Adam".

Comment: `isPalindrome . normalise`, where you define `normalise` so that it removes all the cruft you don't want?

Comment: ummmmm, Im still a bit new at this. Where did the other answers go? no reason. just curious

Comment: Their authors deleted them. One was clearly wrong, and the other was not as nice as melpomene's (my `normailse` is his `strip`, BTW).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import Data.Char (isAlphaNum, toLower)

isPalindromeStripped :: String -> Bool
isPalindromeStripped xs = isPalindrome (strip xs)

strip :: String -> String
strip xs = map toLower (filter isAlphaNum xs)
```

This version uses `strip` to turn `"Madam I'm Adam"` into `"MadamImAdam"` first, then lowercasing it to `"madamimadam"`.

Comment: As a matter of style, the pointfree version is quite idiomatic: `isPalindromeStripped = isPalindrome . map toLower . filter isAlphanum`.